# Definition of Polynomials in Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials, definition

**Definition:** $F[x]$ $=\mathrm{span}(\{x^n|n\geq 0\})$, where $x=(0,1,0,…)$. $f\in F[x]$ is called polynomial over $F$.

It’s easy to check, $F[x]\subseteq F^\Bbb{N}$. **Que:** Why Hoffman’s defines polynomial over $F$ as sequence instead of map $f:F\to F$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\cdot x^i$, for some $a_i\in F$?

Comment: His definition is the same as yours. Spans are sets of finite linear combinations. I’d imagine he wanted to emphasise the fact that $\{x^n\}$ is a basis

Comment: @user264745 Because for a finite field $F$ the homomorphism $\nu:F[x]\to F^F$ defined by $\nu(p)(\alpha)=p(\alpha)$ is not injective. Specifically, $\ker\nu=\langle x^{\lvert F\rvert}-x\rangle$.

Comment: @FShrike Maps and sequence are different things!? Is it customary to define polynomials as sequence?

Comment: It seems like it was *you* who suggested $F[x]\subset F^{\Bbb N}$. That is true in the sense that $F[x]$ can be *identified* as a subset of the sequence space. But morally, it’s better to think of the span-definition. The sequential perspective can help when ascertaining cardinality, though

Comment: @FShrike yup $F[x]$ is subspace of $F^\Bbb{N}$. Can you elaborate on ascertaining cardinality?

Comment: I highly doubt Hoffman/Kunze wrote exactly "$F[x] = \text{span}(\{x^n|n\ge 0\})$, where $x=(0,1,0,\dots)$." The identification with a subset of $F^{\Bbb N}$ is going to be made by associating the polynomial $x^n$ with the vector $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ with a $1$ in precisely the $n+1$ slot. The "where" clause sounds like something a student would write, not authors.

Comment: Huffman seemingly defines the polynomial ring as a span, a linear space. Focus on that rather than on the sequential identification! And, I mean, the question of: “how many polynomials are there?” Can be answered by looking at the cardinality of the set $F^{\Bbb N}$

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, that wasn’t the exact phrasing of definition.

Comment: So why not do the authors the favor of quoting them *exactly*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $F$ is a finite field then polynomials over $F$ are not the same thing as polynomial functions $F \to F$; specifically, if $F = \mathbb{F}_q$ then the polynomial $x^q - x$ vanishes on $F$ but does not vanish as a polynomial. One way to think about this is that a polynomial in $F[x]$ should define a function, not just on $F$, but on every field extension $F \to L$, and $x^q - x$ doesn't vanish on, say, $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I don’t know about finite field and field extension. Can you give link for reference of $\Bbb{F}_q$?

Comment: The Wikipedia article is fine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field